# Regex that allows only single separators between words

Tags: java, regex

I need to construct a regular expression such that it should not allow `/` at the start or end, and there should not be more than one `/` in sequence.

```
Valid Expression is: AB/CD
Valid Expression   :AB
Invalid Expression:  //AB//CD//
Invalid Expression:  ///////
Invalid Expression:  AB////////
```

The `/` character is just a separator between two words. Its length should  not be more than one between words.

Comment: What kinds of characters are allowed between slashes? Also, is `AB` a valid match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to allow alphanumerics (including underscore) between slashes, it's pretty trivial:

```
boolean foundMatch = subject.matches("\\w+(?:/\\w+)*");
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w+  # Match one or more alnum characters
(?:  # Start a non-capturing group
 /   # Match a single slash
 \w+ # Match one or more alnum characters
)*   # Match that group any number of times
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]+(/[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

It matches

```
a/b
a/b/c
aa/vv/cc
```

doesn't matches

```
a
/a/b
a//b
a/b/
```

Demo

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Reg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+(/[a-zA-Z]+)+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("a/b/c");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
    }
}
```

Comment: There are quote a few unnecessary parentheses here, and you should be using `.matches()` instead of `.find()` for validation, or substrings will also be matched.

Comment: What about `abc` or `a/b/c`?

Answer (score 0):

This regex does it:

```
^(?!/)(?!.*//).*[^/]$
```

So in java:

```
if (str.matches("(?!/)(?!.*//).*[^/]"))
```

Note that ^ and $ are implied by `matches()`, because matches must match the *whole* string to be true.